# jquery multipart form submission prevention

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery form submission prevention using `e.preventDefault()` is not working in multipart form submission ( when im using ajax to submit ). Is there any  way to solve it ?

Code

```
$('.imgChange').submit( function(e){
    load('do_upload.php',$(this).serialize());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/wM7rT/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - how to submit a \`post\` \`multipart/form-data\` from a form and get your function called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924157/jquery-how-to-submit-a-post-multipart-form-data-from-a-form-and-get-your-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using normal jQuery library it is not possible sent multipart form using ajax.
There are many other plugin for that.

I recommend [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

it is very easy to use. Only you have to do is import that plugin after jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

then use

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work on multipart form also

HTML

```
<form id="form-id" action="/UploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#form-id').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('submit prevented');
    // rest of the code here
});
```

As long as you do not have anything else overriding this like an `onsubmit`, there is no reason for `.preventDefault()` to not work on multipart forms

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifaqir/1/edit)